# QTMovie initWithMovie:timeRange:error: fails under 10.7 but not 10.6

Tags: qtkit

I have a QTMovie object created from a file. I check that it's a valid movie with which can be played or written to file nicely.

Then this line fails with error:

```
Error code: -50 domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain description: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)
```

(Read permission?)
It happens when the movie is longer than ~15 seconds (this varies). The timerange is verified to be correct and should not result in this error anyway.

```
[[QTMovie alloc] initWithMovie:movie timeRange:range error:&error];
```

The line spawns the 32bit process QTKitServer for a couple of seconds, until it fails.

The error only occurs in Lion but not Snow Leopard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I used the editing functions of QTMovie, either use deleteSegment: of the old movie or create a new movie and use insertSegmentOfMovie:movie to insert the segment from the old to the new movie. Remember to set the editable attribute to yes :)

```
[movie setAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                forKey:QTMovieEditableAttribute];
```